Title: How to Recover IBM DB2 Keystore Files (".sth") Using Scalpel?
I am working on a project where I need to recover IBM DB2 keystore files (with the ".sth" extension) from a disk image. I have been using the Scalpel file carving tool for data recovery but have encountered some challenges in correctly configuring it to find these specific files.
Here are the steps and configurations I have tried so far:
Header and Footer Hexadecimal Search:
plaintext
Kód másolása
sth y 1000 500000 \x8b\xe4\xe2\xde\xb1\x1d\xe6\x0a \x42\x67\x47\x64\xd9\x4d\xdf\x5a\xb6\xf5\x22\x5e\x53\x5c\x1f\xe8
String Search:
For the string "KeyStore":
plaintext
Kód másolása
string KeyStore y 10000000
For the string "keyStores xmi
=":
plaintext
Kód másolása
string keyStores_xmi_id y 1000000 "keyStores xmi:id="
Despite these attempts, I am still having trouble reliably identifying and recovering the .sth files.
Questions:
Are there any specific configurations or additional steps I should take to improve the accuracy of Scalpel in finding and recovering these .sth files?
Is there a better approach or tool for recovering IBM DB2 keystore files from a disk image?
Has anyone successfully recovered .sth files using Scalpel and can share their configuration or methodology?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Your question does not concern programming. A different forum might better suit your question.
